# How Can I Create Joomla Shortcuts Keys for Keyboard Navigation Accessibility

Tags: joomla, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working on web accessibility and Keyboard Navigation so I wanted to work on keyboard shortcuts ,which will help people to work easily.

Comment: You already have a Joomla account.  Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  We would like to see your personal progress on this programming journey.  Please include your research and proof of toil in your question.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, your question might receive snarky comments like "cool story; needs more dragons" because you haven't actually shown where you need help.  Ultimately, I expect your question to be closed as **Needs More Focus**.